# Why does it undefined when it should have defined it?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

After the maze is generated, if you move your player around a bit, soon it'll say "No cell found", which happens whenever the cell is undefined. I don't know why the cell is not in the check array. I really don't know what to do to fix this, or why it's not being added to the array. Also sometimes you can't move a certain direction your supposed to move, and you can move through walls. I think this is because some cells are added twice. My full program is underneath.

```
var cols, rows;
var diffeculty = 0;
var w = 50;
var grid = [];
var stack = [];
var current;
var check = []
var k = 0;
var m = 0;
var won = false;

function setup() {
  //frameRate(10)
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  cols = floor(width / w)
  rows = floor(height / w)


  for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      var cell = new Cell(i, j)
      grid.push(cell)
    }
  }

  current = grid[0];
}
function index(i, j) {

  if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols - 1 || j > cols - 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  return i + j * cols
}

function Cell(i, j) {


  this.visited = false;
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
  this.checkNeighbors = function() {
    var neighbors = []
    var top = grid[index(i, j - 1)]
    var right = grid[index(i + 1, j)]
    var left = grid[index(i - 1, j)]
    var bottom = grid[index(i, j + 1)]
    var Wall = this.walls;
    
    var wall=[]
    wall.push(i,j,Wall)
    
    
    if (top && !top.visited) {
      neighbors.push(top);
    }

    if (right && !right.visited) {
      neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if (bottom && !bottom.visited) {
      neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if (left && !left.visited) {
      neighbors.push(left);
    }

    if (neighbors.length > 0) {
      var r = floor(random(0, neighbors.length))
      return neighbors[r];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }

  }

  this.highlight = function() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 255, 100)
    rect(x, y, w, w);

  }
  this.show = function() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    stroke(255);
    noFill();

    if (this.walls[0]) {
      line(x, y, x + w, y);
    }
    if (this.walls[1]) {
      line(x + w, y, x + w, y + w);
    }

    if (this.walls[2]) {
      line(x + w, y + w, x, y + w);
    }
    if (this.walls[3]) {
      line(x, y + w, x, y);
    }

    if (this.visited) {
      fill(255, 0, 255, 100);
      noStroke();
      rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
  }
};






function removeWalls(a, b) {
  var x = a.i - b.i;
  if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false;
  } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
  }
  var y = a.j - b.j;

  if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false;
  } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
  }


}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].show()
  }


  //Step One
  current.visited = true;
  current.highlight();

  var next = current.checkNeighbors()
  if (next) {
    next.visited = true;

    //Step 2
    stack.push(current);
    check.push(current)

    //Step 3
    removeWalls(current, next) 
    {}


    //Step 4 
    current = next;
  } else if (stack.length > 0) {
    current = stack.pop();

  }


  if (stack[0] === undefined) {
    fill(0, 105, 100)
    rect(0, 0, w, w)
    rect(width - w, height - w, w, w)
    frameRate(8)
  
    
    var c = check.find(cell => cell.i == ~~(k/w) && cell.j == ~~(m/w));
      

if(c===undefined){
   console.log('no cell found');
}else{
   console.log('i',c.i,'j', c.j,'walls', c.walls);
}

    if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)&&!c.walls[0]) {
      k -= w
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)&&!c.walls[1]) {
      m += w
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)&&!c.walls[2]) {
      k += w
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)&&!c.walls[3]) {
      m -= w
    }

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    rect(m, k, w, w)

    if (m < 0) {
      m = 0
    }
    if (k < 0) {
      k = 0
    }
    if (m > width - w) {
      m = width - w
    }
    if (k > height - w) {
      k = height - w
    }

    if (k === height - w && m === width - w || won === true) {

      won = true
      background(0)
      textSize(40)
      text("You Win", width / 2, height / 2)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can spot a couple of problems with function index(i, j):

1. if i is cols and j is rows, then if you if statement, you should check `i > rows - 1` instead of `i > cols - 1`
2. you probably want to return cols-1 instead of cols:

   `return i + j * cols-1;`

Comment: The first one doesn't work because then some part of the maze isn't generated. With the second piece of advice, the result is interesting but not what I'm looking for(which is for it to generate the maze)

Comment: its very possible you have other problems going on. but both of those should be fixed for sure. if i represents rows than it logically doesn't make any sense to check if it is greater than the number of columns.

Comment: The first solution does work a bit of adjustment actually, but the second isn't working..

Comment: you might be right, although its possible you should use `return j + i * cols`. You need to do some very good testing to see if you are in fact getting the right index. Would also help, a lot, if you named your variables row and col instead of j and i. It's very confusing trying to read through your code and keep track of what everything is doing.